# How can I INSERT data into two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert data into two MySQL tables at once..

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user_pass = $_POST['password'];
$user_type = $_POST['tpye'];
$user_street = $_POST['street'];
$user_city = $_POST['city'];
$user_country = $_POST['country'];
$user_email = $_POST['email'];
$user_phone = $_POST['phone'];

$query = "INSERT INTO  fkrv_users 
                    (fkrv_username, fkrv_user_pass, fkrv_user_type, 
                    fkrv_user_street, fkrv_user_city, fkrv_user_cuntry, 
                    fkrv_user_email, fkrv_user_phone) 
           VALUES ('$username','$user_pass','$user_type,',
                   '$user_street','$user_city','$user_country',
                   '$user_email','$user_phone')";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

I need to insert $username and $user_type into table fkrv_list..

I tried with two MySQL queries but does not work.. Here is what I tried..

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user_pass = $_POST['password'];
$user_type = $_POST['tpye'];
$user_street = $_POST['street'];
$user_city = $_POST['city'];
$user_country = $_POST['country'];
$user_email = $_POST['email'];
$user_phone = $_POST['phone'];

$query1 = "INSERT INTO  fkrv_users 
                   (fkrv_username, fkrv_user_pass, fkrv_user_type, 
                    fkrv_user_street, fkrv_user_city, fkrv_user_cuntry, 
                    fkrv_user_email, fkrv_user_phone) 
            VALUES ('$username','$user_pass','$user_type,',
                    '$user_street','$user_city','$user_country',
                    '$user_email','$user_phone')";

$query2 "INSERT INTO  fkrv_list 
                    (fkrv_list_username, fkrv_list_type) 
             VALUES ('$username','$user_type')

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query1,$query2);
```

I also tied with one query and with "AND INSERT INTO" but without success..

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Just run them separately....

Comment: The data has not been saved in MySql tables (fkrv_users or fkrv_list)

Comment: If you absolutely need to run them both at the same time, you can use a transaction: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php. And there's always `mysqli_multi_query`, too

Comment: separately.. what do you meen?

Comment: @JohnStuart mysqli_query($link, $query1); followed by mysqli_query($link, $query2);

Comment: sidenote: plus a typo `$user_type = $_POST['tpye'];`

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Your queries are susceptible to SQL injection. Use PDO bound queries or at the very least mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: resolved.. thanks to everybody!

Comment: that missing closing statement of yours, where is it?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 2):

you can run each one separately like so :

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO  fkrv_users (fkrv_username, fkrv_user_pass, fkrv_user_type, fkrv_user_street, fkrv_user_city, fkrv_user_cuntry, fkrv_user_email, fkrv_user_phone) VALUES ('$username','$user_pass','$user_type,','$user_street','$user_city','$user_country','$user_email','$user_phone')";

$query2 "INSERT INTO  fkrv_list (fkrv_list_username, fkrv_list_type) VALUES ('$username','$user_type')";

$result1 = mysqli_query($link,$query1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2);
```

Comment: you forgot to close a statement because you copied the OP's code, rather than picking up on it.

Comment: I just wrote the solution for the problem .. it's just a part thats not working with him ..thax

Comment: `('$username','$user_type')` will produce a syntax error if not closed. Use `;` which again, should have been signaled.

Comment: Oh never mind; Riggs was kind enough to "fix it for you".

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just had a napp and am feeling all generous

Comment: Still it's vulnerable...You should post more safe answers which are not vulnerable to `SQL Attacks` As @RiggsFolly said in the comments that take a look at [**Little Bobby Tables**](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).Learn Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you have to INSERT 2 times.

However, you can also handle this in a few better ways.

### Option 1: Create a Trigger

```sql
delimiter #

create trigger to_list_from_users_ins_trig after insert on fkrv_users
for each row
begin
  insert into fkrv_list (fkrv_list_username, fkrv_list_type) values     (new.fkrv_username, new.fkrv_user_type);
end#
```

### Option 2: Double Check Your Logic

This should actually be Option 1, but...

Make sure your SQL / Table schema / PHP code is as efficient and well put-together as you can put it. What parts logically go together. What logically fits into a specific domain or category?

If you need to have this field for every user, then it should probably be put in the users table.

What is the purpose of the list table? What do you use the data for?

### Thirdly: a caution.

Your code currently inputs variables directly into the tables.

You should have some form of validation and sanitization going on to prevent things like SQL injection into user forms.

It is **highly** recommended that you escape any user input before you insert it into your database. Not doing so can leave you very vulnerable to attacks and the ability for not so nice people to have fun with your data.

To do so, you can simply do something like:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
```

and etc. for each other variable going into a query.

You can read on the [PHP.net manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)